# Positioning and Velocity Problems in Pygame

Tags: python, position, pygame

I have a Pygame for a Pong-like game, and it looks pretty awesome right now, but there are a few things I can't figure out.

The first problem is a problem with the sides. I've set the bat to move around using the left and right arrow keys and stop when it reaches the side (using positioning), but if you press the left key on the left side or the right key on the right side, it will go outside of the playing area by a little bit.

The second problem, like the first is about the sides too. I've set the ball to move around and bounce of the walls (using positioning), but if the bat is on the left or right side, and I am the holding the corresponding key, the ball will go right through the wall/ceiling!

The final problem is that I've set the ball to speed up over time (using velocity). If you were good at the game, it would speed up until the ball was so fast it had the power to break right through the bat.

This is my code:

```
import pygame, time, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption ("Pong Squash")

def gameplay1():
    global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, font2, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball, points, points_count, new_points, your_score1, space1, esc1, munrosmall, new_positionx, beep_list
    game_over_display = "game_over1.png"
    lives = "lives.png"
    points = "points.png"
    lives_remaining = "lives_remaining.png"
    your_score = "score_intro.png"
    space = "space.png"
    esc = "esc.png"
    munrosmall = "munrosmall.ttf"
    beep1 = "beep1.wav"
    beep2 = "beep2.wav"
    beep3 = "beep3.wav"
    beep4 = "beep4.wav"

    game_over1 = pygame.image.load(game_over_display).convert()
    lives1 = pygame.image.load(lives).convert()
    points1 = pygame.image.load(points).convert()
    lives_remaining1 = pygame.image.load(lives_remaining).convert()
    your_score1 = pygame.image.load(your_score).convert()
    space1 = pygame.image.load(space).convert()
    esc1 = pygame.image.load(esc).convert()

    font1 = pygame.font.Font((munrosmall), 40)
    font2 = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)

    white = 255,255,255
    black = 0, 0, 0
    green = 0, 250, 0
    yellow = 255, 255, 0

    points = 0
    points_count = font1.render(str(points), True, white)
    lives_count = font1.render(('3'), True, white)

    position_x = 175
    position_y = 375
    velocity_x1 = 0
    velocity_y1 = 0
    position1 = 275
    position2 = 150
    velocity1 = 2
    velocity2 = 2

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if waiting:
                        waiting = False
                        reset_ball()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 - 3)
                elif event.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 + 3)
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = 0

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        color = 255
        width = 0
        position = position_x, position_y, 250, 25
        position_x += velocity_x1
        position_y += velocity_y1
        position1 += velocity1
        position2 += velocity2

        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), position, width)
        ball = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), (position1, position2, 15, 15), width)

        if player.colliderect(ball):
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        if position_x > 350 or position_x < 0:
            velocity_x1 = 0
        elif position1 > 575 or position1 < 0:
            velocity1 = - velocity1
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        elif position2 < 0:
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            velocity2 += 0.1
            points += 100
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            pygame.display.update()
        elif position2 > 365:
            new_points = points
            newposition_x = position_x
            change_level1()

        screen.blit(lives1, (450, 455))
        screen.blit(points1,(0, 459))
        screen.blit(lives_count,(560,453))
        points_count = font1.render(str(points), True, white)
        screen.blit(points_count, (150, 456))
        pygame.display.update()

def gameplay2():  
    global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball, points, points_count, new_points, your_score1, munrosmall, newposition_x, beep_list
    game_over_display = "game_over1.png"
    lives = "lives.png"
    points = "points.png"
    lives_remaining = "lives_remaining.png"
    beep1 = "beep1.wav"
    beep2 = "beep2.wav"
    beep3 = "beep3.wav"
    beep4 = "beep4.wav"

    game_over1 = pygame.image.load(game_over_display).convert()
    lives1 = pygame.image.load(lives).convert()
    points1 = pygame.image.load(points).convert()
    lives_remaining1 = pygame.image.load(lives_remaining).convert()

    white = 255,255,255
    black = 0, 0, 0
    green = 0, 250, 0
    yellow = 255, 255, 0

    points_count = font1.render(str(new_points), True, white)
    lives_count = font1.render(('2'), True, white)

    velocity_x1 = 0
    velocity_y1 = 0
    position1 = 275
    position2 = 150
    velocity1 = 2
    velocity2 = 2

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if waiting:
                        waiting = False
                        reset_ball()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 - 3)
                elif event.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 + 3)
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = 0

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        color = 255
        width = 0
        position = position_x, position_y, 250, 25
        position_x += velocity_x1
        position1 += velocity1
        position2 += velocity2

        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), position, width)
        ball = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), (position1, position2, 15, 15), width)

        if player.colliderect(ball):
            velocity1 = - velocity1
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        if position_x > 350 or position_x < 0:
            velocity_x1 = 0
        elif position1 > 575 or position1 < 0:
            velocity1 = - velocity1
            beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
            beep = random.shuffle((beep_list))
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        elif position2 < 0:
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            velocity2 += 0.1
            new_points += 100
            beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            pygame.display.update()
        elif position2 > 365:
            change_level2()

        screen.blit(lives1, (450, 455))
        screen.blit(points1,(0, 459))
        screen.blit(lives_count,(560,453))
        points_count = font1.render(str(new_points), True, white)
        screen.blit(points_count, (150, 456))
        pygame.display.update()
def gameplay3():
    global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball, new_points, new_points2, your_score1, munrosmall, newposition_x, beep_list
    game_over_display = "game_over1.png"
    lives = "lives.png"
    points = "points.png"
    lives_remaining = "lives_remaining.png"
    beep1 = "beep1.wav"
    beep2 = "beep2.wav"
    beep3 = "beep3.wav"
    beep4 = "beep4.wav"

    game_over1 = pygame.image.load(game_over_display).convert()
    lives1 = pygame.image.load(lives).convert()
    points1 = pygame.image.load(points).convert()
    lives_remaining1 = pygame.image.load(lives_remaining).convert()

    white = 255,255,255
    black = 0, 0, 0
    green = 0, 250, 0
    yellow = 255, 255, 0

    points_count = font1.render(str(new_points), True, white)
    lives_count = font1.render(('1'), True, white)

    velocity_x1 = 0
    velocity_y1 = 0
    position1 = 275
    position2 = 150
    velocity1 = 2
    velocity2 = 2

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if waiting:
                        waiting = False
                        reset_ball()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 - 3)
                elif event.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = (velocity_x1 + 3)
            elif event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    velocity_x1 = 0

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        color = 255
        width = 0
        position = position_x, position_y, 250, 25
        position_x += velocity_x1
        position1 += velocity1
        position2 += velocity2

        player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), position, width)
        ball = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, color, color), (position1, position2, 15, 15), width)

        if player.colliderect(ball):
            velocity1 = - velocity1
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            beep_list = [beep1, beep2, beep3, beep4]
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

        if position_x > 350 or position_x < 0:
            velocity_x1 = 0
        elif position1 > 575 or position1 < 0:
            velocity1 = - velocity1
            beep = random.shuffle(beep_list)
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        elif position2 < 0:
            velocity2 = - velocity2
            velocity2 += 0.1
            new_points += 100
            pygame.mixer.music.load((beep_list[1]))
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            pygame.display.update()
        elif position2 > 365:
            game_over()

        screen.blit(lives1, (450, 455))
        screen.blit(points1,(0, 459))
        screen.blit(lives_count,(560,453))
        points_count = font1.render(str(new_points), True, white)
        screen.blit(points_count, (150, 456))
        pygame.display.update()
def change_level1():
    global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball
    gameplay2()
    pygame.display.update()
def change_level2():
    global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball
    gameplay3()
    pygame.display.update()
def reset_ball():
  global game_over_display, lives, points, lives_remaining, game_over1, lives1, points1, lives_remaining1, font1, white, black, green, yellow, lives_number, lives_count, position_x, position_y, velocity_x1, velocity_y1, position1, position2, velocity1, velocity2, color, width, position, player, ball
  velocity1 = 2
  velocity2 = 2
  pygame.display.update()
def game_over():
    global game_over1, your_score1
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(game_over1, (200,100))
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                    gameplay1()
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(your_score1, (100, 175))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)
        points_count = font1.render(str(new_points), True, white)
        screen.blit(points_count, (400, 170))
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(1)
        screen.blit(space1, (115, 250))
        screen.blit(esc1, (175, 300))
        pygame.display.flip()

gameplay1()
```

I really need help with these things. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I kind of fixed the final problem by decreasing the velocity added every time it hits the back wall, but I still need help with the first two. I don't understand the fact that velocityx1 is in anyway related the velocity1. Is it something with the wall position, or is it collision? Please help!

Comment: Heisenberg has same problem xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!

I just had to add a single line of code:

```
    if position_x > 350:
        position_x = 350
        velocity_x1 = 0
    if position_x < 0:
        position_x = 0
        velocity_x1 = 0
```

Position_x  and velocity_x1 are the bat position/ velocity. Telling the system that it absolutely can't go through (using the 'position_x = 0') that certain position fixed both bugs.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need more iterations on collision detection.

P.S.
Box2D - big library with 2d phisics, Euler's equations etc. It has python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just rely on collision detection. Use sanity checks (is position of the player outside of bound? set it to the correct bound).
Set a upper limit on the speed of the ball. Also use path checking. (Is the bat in the ball's move path?)

Also, consider refactoring (renaming your variables) your code so that it is easier for others to pick up what's going on. (I mean, what is position_x? the position of the ball or player??)

For more complex examples in the future, provide a Minimum Working Example. (strip out the unnecessary stuff such as sounds etc)

Good luck!